# how to scroll a painted region?

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to scroll a painted region. I use the CS_OWNDC style with WS_HSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL.My WM_PAINT block draws a line outgoing from the visible region (I suspect that I need to increase the buffer somehow).How can I make this?Please give me an example
PS. Block of code WM_HSCROLL incorrect working i don't know how to fix this.
My code:

```
// C++ WINAPI LEARN
#include <Windows.h>

WNDCLASS windowClass;
HDC hdc;
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
int hScroll, vScroll;
bool first = true;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWindow, UINT typeMessage, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (typeMessage)
    {
        case WM_PAINT:
            hdc = BeginPaint(hWindow, &ps);
            //HERE ANYTHING DRAW CODE (words, line any figure)
            //(draw line out visible region)
            if (first == true)
            {
                first = false;
                MoveToEx(hdc, 5, 5, NULL);
                LineTo(hdc, 900, 500);
            }
            EndPaint(hWindow, &ps);
            break;
        case WM_HSCROLL:
            //SCOLLBAR NOT JOB!
            if (LOWORD(wParam) == SB_LINERIGHT) // this block not job!!!
            {
                hScroll++;
            }
            else if (LOWORD(wParam) == SB_LINELEFT) // this block not job!!!
            {
                hScroll--;
            }
            else if (LOWORD(wParam) == SB_THUMBTRACK)
            {
                hScroll=HIWORD(wParam);
            }
            SetScrollPos(hWindow, SB_HORZ, hScroll, FALSE);
            ScrollWindow(hWindow, hScroll, vScroll, NULL, NULL);
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
            break;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWindow, typeMessage, wParam, lParam);
}

int WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstanse, LPSTR LpszCmdParam, int nCmdShow)
{
    //CREATE WINDOW
    windowClass = { 0 };
    windowClass.lpszClassName = "ScrollTest";
    windowClass.hInstance = hInstance;
    windowClass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    windowClass.style = CS_OWNDC;
    //REGISTER CLASS
    RegisterClass(&windowClass);
    HWND myWindow = ::CreateWindowEx(
        0,
        "ScrollTest",
        "Scroll Paint",
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_HSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL,
        100, 100,
        500, 500,
        NULL,
        0,
        hInstance,
        0
    );
    //TRANSLATE MESSAGE
    for (MSG windowMessage; GetMessage(&windowMessage, NULL, 0, 0);)
    {
        DispatchMessage(&windowMessage);    //TRANSLATE MESSAGES
        TranslateMessage(&windowMessage);   //TRANSLATE KEYS
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please paste your window procedure. Don't answer, edit the question.

Comment: I can't figure out what you are trying to ask for.  Please clarify.

Comment: I fix this theme. Sorry i bad know elglish)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [demo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/scroll-text-in-scroll-bars), I modified part of the code and it works normally.

Some code:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MyTextWindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HDC hdc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    TEXTMETRIC tm;
    SCROLLINFO si;

    // These variables are required to display text. 
    static int xChar;       // horizontal scrolling unit 
    static int yChar;       // vertical scrolling unit 

    static int xPos;        // current horizontal scrolling position 
    static int yPos;        // current vertical scrolling position 

    int x, y;               // horizontal and vertical coordinates

    // Create an array of lines to display. 
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        // Get the handle to the client area's device context. 
        hdc = GetDC(hwnd);

        // Extract font dimensions from the text metrics. 
        GetTextMetrics(hdc, &tm);
        xChar = tm.tmAveCharWidth;
        yChar = tm.tmHeight + tm.tmExternalLeading;

        // Free the device context. 
        ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);

        return 0;

    case WM_HSCROLL:
        // Get all the vertial scroll bar information.
        si.cbSize = sizeof(si);
        si.fMask = SIF_ALL;

        // Save the position for comparison later on.
        GetScrollInfo(hwnd, SB_HORZ, &si);
        xPos = si.nPos;
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
            // User clicked the left arrow.
        case SB_LINELEFT:
            si.nPos -= 1;
            break;

            // User clicked the right arrow.
        case SB_LINERIGHT:
            si.nPos += 1;
            break;

            // User clicked the scroll bar shaft left of the scroll box.
        case SB_PAGELEFT:
            si.nPos -= si.nPage;
            break;

            // User clicked the scroll bar shaft right of the scroll box.
        case SB_PAGERIGHT:
            si.nPos += si.nPage;
            break;

            // User dragged the scroll box.
        case SB_THUMBTRACK:
            si.nPos = si.nTrackPos;
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        // Set the position and then retrieve it.  Due to adjustments
        // by Windows it may not be the same as the value set.
        si.fMask = SIF_POS;
        SetScrollInfo(hwnd, SB_HORZ, &si, TRUE);
        GetScrollInfo(hwnd, SB_HORZ, &si);

        // If the position has changed, scroll the window.
        if (si.nPos != xPos)
        {
            ScrollWindow(hwnd, xChar * (xPos - si.nPos), 0, NULL, NULL);
        }

        return 0;

    case WM_VSCROLL:
        // Get all the vertial scroll bar information.
        si.cbSize = sizeof(si);
        si.fMask = SIF_ALL;
        GetScrollInfo(hwnd, SB_VERT, &si);

        // Save the position for comparison later on.
        yPos = si.nPos;
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {

            // User clicked the HOME keyboard key.
        case SB_TOP:
            si.nPos = si.nMin;
            break;

            // User clicked the END keyboard key.
        case SB_BOTTOM:
            si.nPos = si.nMax;
            break;

            // User clicked the top arrow.
        case SB_LINEUP:
            si.nPos -= 1;
            break;

            // User clicked the bottom arrow.
        case SB_LINEDOWN:
            si.nPos += 1;
            break;

            // User clicked the scroll bar shaft above the scroll box.
        case SB_PAGEUP:
            si.nPos -= si.nPage;
            break;

            // User clicked the scroll bar shaft below the scroll box.
        case SB_PAGEDOWN:
            si.nPos += si.nPage;
            break;

            // User dragged the scroll box.
        case SB_THUMBTRACK:
            si.nPos = si.nTrackPos;
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        // Set the position and then retrieve it.  Due to adjustments
        // by Windows it may not be the same as the value set.
        si.fMask = SIF_POS;
        SetScrollInfo(hwnd, SB_VERT, &si, TRUE);
        GetScrollInfo(hwnd, SB_VERT, &si);

        // If the position has changed, scroll window and update it.
        if (si.nPos != yPos)
        {
            ScrollWindow(hwnd, 0, yChar * (yPos - si.nPos), NULL, NULL);
            UpdateWindow(hwnd);
        }

        return 0;

    case WM_PAINT:
        // Prepare the window for painting.
        hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        // Get vertical scroll bar position.
        si.cbSize = sizeof(si);
        si.fMask = SIF_POS;
        GetScrollInfo(hwnd, SB_VERT, &si);
        yPos = si.nPos;

        // Get horizontal scroll bar position.
        GetScrollInfo(hwnd, SB_HORZ, &si);
        xPos = si.nPos;
       
        x = xChar * (1 - xPos);
        y = yChar * (1 - yPos);
            

        MoveToEx(hdc, 5 + x, 5 + y, NULL);
        LineTo(hdc, 900 + x, 500 + y);
        
        // Indicate that painting is finished.
        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        return 0;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Debug:

[image]

Comment: Hmmm it's full redraw. Is there a way to implement it via buffer, or is there no such way?
And what's faster buffer or redrawing? Big thanks you!!!

Comment: @LEGENDAwarc If you review the official example carefully, you will find that the example only redraws the invalid area without printing all the text. I think this is a very efficient method.

Comment: @LEGENDAwarc The code I gave is just to provide a direction, after all, this is just a very simple straight line. For complex graphics, only drawing the invalid area is a good way to improve efficiency.

Comment: @LEGENDAwarc Hi, If this answer is useful to you, you can mark it. This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread. [How to accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)